# SQL ORA 935: Missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have gone over the SQL for an hour and can't find why the error is being raised. I have checked all the basic reasons this error can occur and found nothing. I'm suspicious of the CASE statement but it appears to be correct. Can anyone spot the problem or point me in a direction? Thanks

```
INSERT INTO RPT_HOUSEHLDBATCH
         (CUSTOMERKEY,HOUSEHOLDNBR,CUSTOMERTYPE,LASTNAME,FIRSTNAME,ADDRNBR,AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3,
         CITYNAME, STATECD, ZIPCD, SCORE, DATECREATED, RUNDATE, TYPECD, PREVIOUSHHLDNBR)
         SELECT CustomerKey,' || in_HHNbr || ', 
         CASE SUBSTR(CUSTOMERKEY,1,1)
    WHEN ''P'' THEN ''I''
    WHEN ''O'' THEN ''B''
   END CASE,
   a.LastName, 
   a.FirstName, 
   AddrNbr, 
   AddressLine1, 
   AddressLine2, 
   AddressLine3,
   Cityname, 
   StateCd,
   ZipCd, 
   2, b.AddDate, SYSDATE, ''' || in_NewUpd || ''', HouseHoldNbr
   FROM rpt_HouseHldBatchwrk a
JOIN PERS b
ON SUBSTR(a.CUSTOMERKEY,2) = b.PersNbr 
   WHERE CUSTOMERKEY = ''P' || in_PersNbr || '''
UNION 
SELECT CustomerKey,' || in_HHNbr || ', 
         CASE SUBSTR(CUSTOMERKEY,1,1)
    WHEN ''P'' THEN ''I''
    WHEN ''O'' THEN ''B''
   END CASE,
   a.LastName, 
   a.FirstName, 
   AddrNbr, 
   AddressLine1, 
   AddressLine2, 
   AddressLine3,
   Cityname, 
   StateCd,
   ZipCd, 
   2, b.AddDate, SYSDATE, ''' || in_NewUpd || ''', HouseHoldNbr
   FROM rpt_HouseHldBatchwrk a
JOIN ORG b
ON SUBSTR(a.CUSTOMERKEY,2) = b.OrgNbr 
   WHERE CUSTOMERKEY = ''O' || in_OrgNbr || '''
```

Comment: SO here's what you do to solve this - pare back the query to bare-bones, then start adding parts back until you get the error, and then you will know where the error is.  SO is not for checking syntax.

Comment: Why dio you have things like this ''P'' (2 quotes before and after)

Comment: This sql is stored in a variable and gets executed based on a condition. So the whole thing lives inside '' which is why the quotes are escaped.

Comment: Every use of a quote or the combination of them is incorrect. I suggest you first get the query to run standalone, then use the 
[Alternative Quoting Mechanism](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html) which makes double quoting unnecessary to assign it to a variable.

Comment: I'm curious what debugging method did you use that you have "gone over the SQL for an hour and can't find why the error is being raised".  I can clearly see those extra quotes within a few seconds of looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

A good strategy to debug such a statement is to pare it down, as @OldProgrammer suggested.

In your case, I'd try to ignore the `INSERT` and get the `SELECT` running first.

As it's a `UNION` of two `SELECT`s, I'd split them into separate statements, too.

The `in_NewUpd` and `in_PersNbr` look strange, just like parameters in a procedure. I'd replace them with fixed known values, like `WHERE CUSTOMERKEY LIKE ''P1234''`

And please, please don't store SQL in a variable and execute it based on a condition. The syntax for that is to use placeholder like `?` in the SQL instead of string concatenation `||`. You'll flood the cursor cache if you do it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the in_HHNbr in some cases was coming in as a null. Concatenating null throws missing expression.

As far as how the code is structured I inherited this code and can't make major changes. I was sent to bug fix.

Comment: Well, I don't consider changing the query string as a major change, as you have to fix it anyway. I'd strongly suggest to use placeholders like

   stmt := 'INSERT INTO t SELECT CustomerKey, :in_hhnbr, CASE ...'
   EXECUTE IMMEDATIATE stmt USING in_hhnbr;

Comment: Besides, your spending an hour going over the SQL not spotting the NULL value is proving the point why you shouldn't concatenating SQL statements. Been there just too many times...